# JFrog Artifactory: Difference between build, package, and artifact

Tags: continuous-integration, artifactory

I'm looking for a flushed out definition, and haven't been able to find any. I found a  post, such as [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/what-is-the-difference-between-packages-and-artifacts), but many other posts are incomplete or unanswered. I simply want to know the difference between a build, package, and artifact. I don't know if those mean different things on different platforms, but FWIW, I'm using JFrog.

Answer (score 5):

An artifact is a file. A package, in artifactory, is like a folder; it is a namespace where artifacts published under it's name are stored. The package name and artifact name will be the same, and are comprised of the groupId and artifactId. The artifact name includes a version suffix; the package does not, as it contains all versions of artifacts with that name.

Artifactory provides a package view, and an artifact view. The package view provides information about the package (number of versions stored, number of times each version has been downloaded, etc). The artifact view allows you to drill down to individual artifact versions, inspect artifact details (when created, by whom, etc), and download the artifact itself.

The build view contains information about how a given artifact was created/assembled, but only if you have a jfrog/artifactory build client integrated into your build server, which will then collect information during the build process and publish it to artifactory along with the artifact itself.

Hope that helps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qr7kZ_Nluww

[https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-integrations-documentation/overview?tocId=M6IuL6IZjrSuuzPkBaKW~Q](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-integrations-documentation/overview?tocId=M6IuL6IZjrSuuzPkBaKW%7EQ)